# Find the limit of $\dfrac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{\int_1^e \ln ^n (1+e^{nx})}$ as $n\to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find the limits :
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{\int_1^e \ln ^n (1+e^{nx})}=?$$

My Try :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{\int_1^e \ln ^n (1+e^{nx})}{n^2}}=?$$

Now $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=$ Then $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}=l$

But I do not get any results please help me

Answer (score 3):

From $\log(1+e^{nx})=nx+O(e^{-nx})$ and $x\in[1,e]$ you get $\log^n(1+e^{nx})= n^n x^n\left(1+O(e^{-nx})\right)=n^n x^n(1+o(1))$.
By integrating both sides over $[1,e]$ you get
$$ \int_{1}^{e}\log^n(1+e^{nx})\,dx = n^n e^{n}(e+o(1)) $$
then
$$ \sqrt[n]{\int_{1}^{e}\log^2(1+e^{nx})\,dx} = n e (1+o(1)) $$
and by dividing both sides by $\frac{1}{n}$ and considering the limit as $n\to +\infty$ we get $\ell=\color{red}{e}$.